# Batch Transfer ERC20 Tokens From One Wallet To Another Wallet

Tags: solidity, web3js, erc-20, ethers.js

Is it possible to batch transfer ERC20 tokens from one wallet to another with one transaction call?

For example, one wallet has 10 ERC20 tokens. We want to get all the ERC20 token contracts in wallet A and then transfer all the 10 ERC20 tokens to wallet B in one Metamask transaction.

I see other multisend & solidity contracts that allow you to do one token to multiple addresses, but we want to do multiple tokens in one wallet to another singular address.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its quite possible. you may try using https://drain.on.fleek.co/